# App Engine Standard: Timeout gave me 500 error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have worked with app engine standard for a year and recently I'm receiving a increased number of 500 error. I tried to test in my local environment and everything works. The problem happens only in production.

I don't know where I can find more information about this error.

> The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time.

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 10  # default value
  min_pending_latency: 30ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: 100ms
```

I already checked the PHP and everything related to timeouts and memory, however the error only happens in App Engine Standard Production.

[Edit]
The last version of the software went live in 09-03-2018 and I didn't receive any problem, the latency problems started in 09-07-2018.

[image: Latency Graph]

I don't know if something change in app engine structure on day seven.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: With the default instance in GAE Std, you get approx 60 seconds to complete a request.  What has changed to make your request take longer than that?  More entities, more operations, more fetches? You may need to send some long-running processes to the task queue (the 60 sec limit is raised).  Or, spin up a new `Service`, which you can set to run longer (that may cost more $).

Comment: It's very strange, because nothing changed on the application. I added a print with the recent latency. My last update was on 09-03-2018.

Answer (score 0):

You have something similar to the [deadlineexceeded error](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors). If you look at the logs in your Cloud Console, you are likely to see this error. You can see various reason and suggested resolutions in the documentation. Basically, either make sure your request is shorter or put it in a task.